# Adding Oil to A/C Compressor After Refrigerant Leak?

Tags: toyota, oil, r134a, refrigerant

I recently retrofitted the A/C system on my 1987 Toyota 4Runner for R134a. This included: resealing original Denso 10P15C compressor, flushing the evaporator, condenser, and lines, installing a new drier, and adding the correct amount of PAG oil as per the Toyota factory service bulletin. Unfortunately the high side R134a adapter fitting leaked and now there is no refrigerant left in the system. I am in the process of finding the correct fitting.

My question is, does more oil have to be added to the system when adding more refrigerant? After it is vacuumed. My guess is no because I do not want to overfill the oil.

Comment: Add the full amount recommended after flushing and re-seal of compressor.